# Perl 2d Array Push

Tags: arrays, perl

Why is there a difference in the creation of the following arrays @test1 and @test2?

```
#!/bin/perl -w
use Data::Dumper;
use warnings;
use strict;

my @test1 = [
     ['note', 1],
     ['note', 3]
];

print Dumper(@test1);

my @test2;
push(@test2, ['note', 1]);
push(@test2, ['note', 3]);

print Dumper(@test2);
```

Datadump for test1:

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        'note',
        1
      ],
      [
        'note',
        3
      ]
    ];
```

Dumpt for test2:

```
$VAR1 = [
          'note',
          1
        ];
$VAR2 = [
          'note',
          3
        ];
```

Is there a possibility to create the same result of @test1 with iterative pushing to @test2?

Comment: Try `push(@{$test2[0]}, ['note', 1])`. Also note that  `@array = [ [1], [2]]`, is not the same as `@array = ( [1], [2] )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of:

```
my @test1 = [
     ['note', 1],
     ['note', 3]
];
```

You probably want:

```
my @test1 = (
     ['note', 1],
     ['note', 3]
);
```

The square brackets will create an anonymous array and will return a reference to the new array.  So `@test1` will contain a single scalar value which is a reference to an array.

Also when dumping a structure like an array, it is often clearer to prefix it with a backslash in order to pass a reference:

```
print Dumper(\@test2);
```

Which gives:

```
$VAR1 = [
      [
        'note',
        1
      ],
      [
        'note',
        3
      ]
    ];
```

Remember when you pass an array in a Perl function call, the array gets "flattened" into the argument list.

Comment: Thanks! But I want to get the same result as in test1 but with using push!

Comment: That's an unusual thing to want.  In your original example code, `@test1` is an array containing a single element whereas @test2 is an array of two elements.